# POST data lost when using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-post

I have this .htaccess file who does some redirecting and rewriting (removing extensions .. etc) but when i send data using the POST method it gets lost along the way.

tried adding this condition to stop Request with POST data from redirecting but it's not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine  On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^resume-.*/([0-9]+)$ /book.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^channel-books/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /getChannelBooks.php?idChaine=$1&page=$2&orderby=$3 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^channel-books/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /getChannelBooks.php?idChaine=$1&$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^chaine-.*/([0-9]+)$ /model_contenu_de_chaine.php?idChaine=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^search-([0-9]+)$ /search_page.php?search=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^audio-([0-9]+)$ /audiobook.php?id=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R=307]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Here's what my post request looks like

[image]

and this is the code in my destroy_session.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'logout'){
   session_unset("username");
   session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: BTW, that's the last version of .htaccess i have, I tried placing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` in different conditions and also tried `R=307` and `R=301`

Comment: What is the request being sent? `tried adding this condition`, which condition? If `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` you won't reach that for the `,L` rules.

Comment: im sending this raw data {action='logout'} with POST method to this php page destroy_session.php

Comment: RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(yourpage.php) - [L]  

try this

Comment: @ManiSingh Tried this one too, Not working.

Comment: Don't know what the request is so can't help. Rules execute procedural though so if you want a behavior to supercede others make it early.

Comment: I edited the question so you have better idea on what's going on, if you want more infos please feel free.

Comment: Looks to me as if this had nothing to do with URL rewriting in the first place. _"Here's what my post request looks like"_ - PHP is not going to populate $_POST, if you send a raw request like that. You need to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's what my post request looks like

That's the actual issue here, this not related to the URL rewriting.

PHP is not going to populate `$_POST`, if you send a raw request like that. You need to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.